# Change only active div and not all classes with same name

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a set of classes with a button, when I'm pressing the button on one of them. The change become in all the classes. But I want it only be on the active div.

I know I should use $this. but I haven't be able to manage it. Any ideas ?

```
function close(){
      $('.close').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "php/functions.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "php",
            success: function(html) {
               var note =  $(".note").html(html);
            }

        });

 return false;
});
}
```

The php file is just containing an echo

```
<?php echo "Heloo" ?>
```

The html

```
<div class="note">
<div class="close"></div>
</div>
<div class="note">
<div class="close"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is this-

```
$('.close').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    url: "php/functions.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "php",
    success: function(html) {
        $this.closest(".note").html(html);
        //or
        $this.parent().html(html);
        //or
        $this.parent().html(html);
    }
  });
});
```

However, this will overwrite your close div. If you want to keep your close div -

HTML:

```
<div class="notewrap">
  <div class="note"></div>
  <div class="close"></div>
</div>
<div class="notewrap">
  <div class="note"></div>
  <div class="close"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript (only use one of the provided options in the callback):

```
$('.close').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    url: "php/functions.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "php",
    success: function(html) {
        //Option 1 - will work even if you change the html structure a fair bit
        $this.parents(".notewrap").find(".note").html(html);
        //Option 2 - will only work if your structure remains very similar
        $this.siblings(".note").html(html);
        //Option 3
        $this.parent().find(".note").html(html);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! this was a great solution, actually the thing i want to do is remove the whole box. Is it possible ?

Comment: Make your callback $this.parent().remove();

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.close').click(function() {
     $(this).addClass("SOMETHING"); <--- like this
        $.ajax({
            url: "php/functions.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "php",
            success: function(html) {
               var note =  $(".note").html(html);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Hi, well I still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to just change the button that was clicked within the ajax `success` callback? This won't work in the callback because it won't return the button (it returns window I think. Not certain).
You have to get a reference to the button before the ajax post. Try this:

```
$('.close').click(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/functions.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: "php",
        success: function(html) {
            //Now you can do whatever you want with 'self', which is the button that was clicked
            self.addClass('myclasstoadd');
            var note =  $(".note").html(html);
        }
    });
```

Comment: exactly . Will try this :) brb

Comment: I tried, but got the same result on both div and not only on one :(

Comment: I will try since it including a php brb.

Comment: Hey. have troubel wit the php and jsFiddle. can send you the link to the project private ?